# How to add multiple columns to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have these two dataframes:

| worker_name | worker_age |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 35 |
| John | 65 |
| Karl | 26 |

| worker_name | duties | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Simon | Plumber | Walmart |
| Alex | Analyst | Amazon |
| John | Driver | Uber |

How can I get such a dataframe?

| worker_name | worker_age | duties | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 35 | Analyst | Amazon |
| John | 65 | Driver | Uber |
| Karl | 26 | Nan | Nan |

I tried going through iteration with df.iterrows() but it takes too much time so it's not the option for my data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge()`. Example taken from [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging):

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
    }
)


right = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)

result = pd.merge(left, right, on="key")
```

Comment: Greetings. It did work but it also removed the keys that were not present in the right dataframes which is not the case for me unfortunately.
P.S. I tried how = "left". Seems like it worked.

Comment: The reason that keys that do not appear in both DataFrames are deleted is because by default, merge() uses how='inner', so it will perform an intersection (only keep keys that appear in both frames). You can change this behaviour by defining your own "how" parameter. The linked documentation provides more details on this.